# a script function to find the first empty column in a specific row

Tags: google-apps-script, autofill

I need a script function to locate the first empty Column cell in a Specific Row of existing data. My Data is stored horizontally with a different customer on every row. Their purchases are added by item and price in the next two columns in their row. The headings for I2:AW2 are Column pairs of Item Description and Price.  This question was asked in 2019 by someone but all of the answers did not solve the question asked. Every answer was how to find the first Column in the first empty row. Those answers did not solve his problem, nor mine.

This is used specifically for charity auctions.  The data sheet is started with data collection using a data entry form adding: bidder #, Name,email, phone #, entry tickets and merchadise sales.  All data is collected during a 4 hour period in a ramdom order as a new item is purchased, I use the data entry form to search for the bidder either by name or bidder #.  With the returned row, I need to find out the next empty cell(Column) in their specific row and add the item that they bought and the price they paid.  I can do everything but this,  add item and cost because it is data stored horizontally not vertically.

I found a formula using "=INDEX(a4:ArrayFormula(Max(COLUMN(A4:4)*(--(A4:4)<>""))))" that works if typed directly into the spreadsheet but I need to have it as an app script function so it will add the data from the data entry form.

I tried making it into a function by using the formula to set a variable and use it in the function to append data in the next two empty cells labelsd Item Detail and Price.  No matter how I try to use it in the script I am unable to save it without an error.

Answer (score 0):

Add one to this return value.

```
function getRowWidth(row, sh, ss) {
  var ss = ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = sh || ss.getActiveSheet();
  var row = row || sh.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var rcA = [];
  if(sh.getLastColumn()){rcA = sh.getRange(row, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().flat().reverse();}
  let s = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < rcA.length; i++) {
    if (rcA[i].toString().length == 0) {
      s++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return rcA.length - s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cooper,

It doesn't quite work.  I had to kind of tweek it a little.  I put in console.log in a few places to see where it was going awry and got it to actually give back data.  I will continue to monkey with it to see if I can make it work.

Comment: I use it quite a bit in my own code.   Perhaps  I misunderstand what you are looking for.  This code provides with length of a row and so the length + 1 is the first empty column after the end of data for the row.  If you actually want the first empty column that may fall within the data then this won't do it for you.